# Removing the active language

Tags: theming

I'm having some trouble with removing the active language from the [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) module. I'm trying to override `theme_languageicons_icon()` with the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function themename_languageicons_icon(&$variables) {
  global $language;

  foreach ($variables as $varKey => $value) {
    if ($variables['language']->language == $language->language) {
      unset($variables[$varKey]);
      break;    
    }
  }

  return theme('links', $variables);
}
```

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this? I don't want to disable the active language using CSS since I'm having different style properties for the first-child and last-child of the list.

Comment: Have you considered blind and other people with disabilities? For them selecting language that's active may be easiest way to cancel selection they entered unintentionally, and you want to take it away from them. Do you really want to make their lives a tiny bit harder than it already is?

Comment: Well I never really considered that thank you for pointing it out, but I still want to know how to remove the active language from the list since its a design requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar problem (removing the language switch links for non-translated equivalent pages), I've implemented [hook_language_switch_links_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!language.api.php/function/hook_language_switch_links_alter/7) in my theme.

Although I haven't tried it out myself, I think the code example will point you in the right direction. Instead of setting an 'active-language' class attribute, you can unset the link.

```
function mymodule_language_switch_links_alter(array &$links, $type, $path) {
  global $language;

  if ($type == LANGUAGE_TYPE_CONTENT && isset($links[$language->language])) {
    foreach ($links[$language->language] as $link) {
      $link['attributes']['class'][] = 'active-language';
    }
  }
}
```